# PHP CSV showing in table

Tags: php, html-table, import-from-csv

I want to show this CSV File the same way as the picture but then in PHP.
Right now I know how to show it if they were all under "A", 
but I'm stuck now on how to show it with more then one cell.

```
<?php
echo "<table border='1'>";
if (($handle = fopen("top10.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",");
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        echo "<tr>";
        $num = count($data);
        for ($i=0; $i < $num; $i++) {
            echo"<td>" . $data[$i] . "<br /> </td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

This is how I did it with 2 rows.

Image:

[image]

Result right now:

Comment: Why are you putting a break tag inside of the table cell?

Comment: so how is this code not working? I can't see any reason why it wouldn't spit out a table with the same rows/cells as the csv.

Comment: Jay Blanchard, Hi do you mean after the </td>?
@Marc B It is working but not correctly, right now it shows the first row in one cell and the rest is not very logically too. Hold on I'll upload the result.

Comment: No, right here `<br /> </td>`.

Comment: so look at the generated html and figure out why it's not working. e.g. `view source` in your browser. maybe your csv contains html and there's some tags in there breaking your table.

Comment: Found the answer guys, had to replace ";" for "," in: $data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",");

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `SplFileObject` which can parse `CSV` files. For example:

```
$file = new SplFileObject("/path/to/your/csv/file.csv");
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
$rows = "";
foreach ($file as $row) {
    list ($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g, $h, $i, $j, $k, $l) = $row;

    $rows .= <<<HTML
<tr>
    <td>${a}</td>
    <td>${b}</td>
    <td>${c}</td>
    <td>${d}</td>
    <td>${e}</td>
    <td>${f}</td>
    <td>${g}</td>
    <td>${h}</td>
    <td>${i}</td>
    <td>${j}</td>
    <td>${k}</td>
    <td>${l}</td>
</tr>
HTML;
}

echo "<table>".$rows."</table>";
```

[PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/splfileobject.setcsvcontrol.php)

Answer (score 0):

you read file 2times in your code:

```
$data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",");// 1st  (just remove this line)
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) { // 2nd
```

and another solution
try this:

```
echo "<table border=\"1\">";
$row=@explode("\n",@file_get_contents('test.csv'));
if(count($row)>0) foreach($row as $r){
    $col=@explode(",",$r);
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($col as $c){
        echo "<td>$c</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}   
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: This solution usually works in small setups where the csv file is a couple of lines. You would face some significant performance decrease once the csv file size increases.